# Web Service Passing parameter Class

Tags: c#, web-services, parameters

Hello I have a web service that has a parameter class

```
    [WebMethod]
    public int Customers(Customer _customers)
    {

        Customer getCustomer = new Customer();
        getCustomer.ID = _customers.ID;
        getCustomer.FirstName = _customers.FirstName;
        getCustomer.LastName = _customers.LastName;

        return 0;
    }
```

now I have a C# console application calling the webservice

```
        ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient _client = new WebService1SoapClient();

        Customer _customers = new Customer();
        _customers.ID = 1;
        _customers.FirstName = "FirstName";
        _customers.LastName = "LAstName";

        _client.Customers(_customers);
```

one the `_client.Customers(_customers);` I have an error

> "cannot convert from 'Customer' to 'WRTC_BACKUPDB.ServiceReference1.Customer'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have 2 `Customer` classes on the client side

Changing

```
Customer _customers = new Customer();
```

to

```
var _customers = new WRTC_BACKUPDB.ServiceReference1.Customer();
```

Should solve this, although you should also determine where the other `Customer` class came from.

It may be that the console client has both a proxied `Customer` class created by the wizard when adding the `Service Reference`, and it also directly references the original `Customer` class used on the server assembly. If you wish to share the same class between client and server, there is an option to reuse type in the Service Reference wizard.

(also from a naming convention viewpoint, I would also change the variable name to `_customer`)

Comment: I have only 1 Customer Class.

Comment: `WRTC_BACKUPDB.ServiceReference1.Customer` is the type expected by `ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient.Customers(...)`. If the client `Customer` was this type, you wouldn't receive the error. Also note my edit w.r.t var / full type when instantiating `WRTC_BACKUPDB.ServiceReference1.Customer` .